# Dapper updates returned datetime format

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have tried to find similar question, but failed, so will create new question.

1. This is what stored on Db:

   [image: database result]
2. This is what gets returned:

   [image]

Is there a way to disable any formatting?

Or some explicit mapping should be done, etc.?

Comment: Why does the format of what is returned matter? Can you format the string text wherever required? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Datetime's don't have a format.   They are a simple number that counts the number of ticks since epoch.  It's only when you convert a datetime to a string that a format is applied, and by giving it no specific format, it is using the default datetime format for the current culture of the thread.  By the looks of it, yours appears to be en-US.

Comment: Result1 is likely the one you want.  It is still a pure datetime.  Result2 you have told dapper you want the datetimes to be converted to a string, so in this case, a format was applied to the datetime, and now it is a string.  You really should not do that.  Conversion from datetime to a formatted string should be done at the very last possible moment in your program.  In an MVC application, that would be in the view.

Comment: Thanks Robert, somehow I even lost sense of just transforming to date format I need.. Mondays .. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@robert-mckee gave you the answer in the comments: the way you bring the results back for `result1` is the cleanest way.  If you return data as a `DateTime` object you are free to format it any way you want in your view after mapping.